# what is the way to solve the issue when loading jquerys of different versions

Tags: jquery, conflict

I am using a widget on a page. 
The page is using jQuery 1.3.2 and many jQuery plugins on this page rely on jQuery 1.3.2. the widget is using jQuery 1.7.1, and many jQuery plugins serving for the widget rely on jQuery 1.7.1. The problem is when I use the sidjs library to load the widget to the page. There are conflicts that cause javascript errors because of jquery versions. I look up the internet and find out that I can use "$.noConflict()" to solve this. But I need to change codes at many places. I think I also need to change the code of the jQuery plugins. Is there any good methods to do this?

Comment: How hard could it be to update the code that apparently relies on 1.3.2 to 1.7.1? The syntax didn't change that much.

Comment: I think its better for you to use a compatible jquery version that will fit the plugins that u are using. try it on jsfiddle

Comment: what do you mean by "The syntax didn't change that much"? you mean the "$.noConflict()" syntax will not do the work well?

Comment: **David** most stuff is backwards compatible.

Comment: @David - What elclanrs said. There are very few deprecated methods to begin with and of those I'm not even sure any were removed between 1.3.2 and 1.7.1. Have you tried just running the plugins using 1.7.1 only?

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
window.$jq171 = jQuery.noConflict();
```

to it's own .js file, and use SidJS to load it immediately afterwards if you are loading jQuery 1.7.1. The only way I can think of that would be easier than that is to add that same line at the very end of the jquery-1.7.1.js or the jquery-1.7.1.min.js file (whichever you're using). Personally, I'd keep it in it's own file.

Then in your scripts that reference jQuery 1.7.1, use `$jq171` in place of the `$` that you would normally type. Example follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //normal style
});
```

becomes:

```
$jq171(document).ready(function () {
    //normal style
});
```